# disable right click in fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

is there a way to disable right click in fancybox.
thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
                onComplete: function() {
                        $("#fancybox-img").bind("contextmenu",function(e){
                            return false;
                        });
                    }
```

Add that to your options to disable right clicking on images in fancybox :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I did that:

```
// fancybox
jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'elastic',
    closeEffect : 'elastic',
    beforeShow: function () {
        /* Disable right click */
        $.fancybox.wrap.bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
        return false;
        });
        /* Disable drag */
        $.fancybox.wrap.bind("dragstart", function (e) {
        return false;
        });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to disable the right click on image, you need to grab the resultant selector and disable its context menu property.

**example** :

```
$('#fancybox-wrap').bind('contextmenu', function() {
    alert('sorry, Right Click Disabled :P'); //do stuff
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This only works once. If the modal is closed and reopened then right click is no longer disabled with an alert.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery then try this. If this helps put some +1 :)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // No right click
    $(document).bind('contextmenu', function() 
    {
        alert('no right click.');
        return false;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late to submit an answer. I just wanna help anyone who didn't know that fancybox add more parameter to protect the data. just add

```
    $('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({
    protect: true
    });
```

[references](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/)